# Can I change UIColor value without creating a new instance?

Tags: ios, swift, pass-by-reference, uicolor

I feel like I'm going crazy for something that might be really simple. UIColor is a class, therefore a reference type, but I can't wrap my head around as to how why. To change a color I find myself simply creating a new instance, instead of holding on to the same reference and changing one of its properties (so I end up adopting a "value type" behavior).

Am I missing something here? **How do I treat UIColor as a reference type when I want to change color** (say, changing its hex or rgba)?

Here's my example:

I have a `var primaryColor = UIColor!` and `var secondaryColor = UIColor!` inside a custom UIView. I also have a couple "sub-variables" (i.e. `borderColor`, `mainTitleColor`, `subTitleColor`) to which I assign the reference of either `primaryColor` or `secondaryColor` during `awakeFromNib`.

The issue is that if I change the value of `primaryColor` or `secondaryColor` color at runtime, the values of the sub-variables (borderColor, mainTitleColor, etc.) don't change, and I understand it's because I'm assigning a new instance of UIColor instead of changing the instance's properties.

So my question is this: **is there a way to maintain the same instance of UIColor, yet change its 'color' value?** I hope that makes sense.

My current workaround is property observers on the `primaryColor` and `secondaryColor` variables, each one changing all the sub-variables if they match the `oldValue`)

Comment: You can use a didSet closure

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned in the last paragraph, I'm using willSet, but it definitely feels like a workaround.

Comment: `var bgColor: UIColor = .red {
    didSet {
        print("new color", bgColor)
    }
}`

Comment: Just because it's a class doesn't mean it's mutable

Comment: MadProgrammer -- thanks for the response! so you're saying I'm using it as intended? :)